# Laravel loses order when querying

Tags: laravel

I have a collection of ids as follows:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "102"
  1 => "101"
]
```

Please notice that order matters.

When I query the model like:

```
$models = Post::whereIn('id', $keys)->get();
```

it loses the order.

So I expect that post with id 102 comes before 101 but 101 comes first.

How can I force query builder to keep the order

Comment: The order of the IDs in an `IN` statement do not determine the order of the results. You'll need to use an `orderBy` statement to accomplish that.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: It depends, what are you trying to order your results by? Just in case, documentation [can be found here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$ids_ordered = implode(',', $keys);

$models = Post::whereIn('id', $keys)
              ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $ids_ordered)"))
              ->get();
```

Reference [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `orderBy()` method on the `id` column

`$models = Post::whereIn('id', $keys)->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();`