# How to make Laravel whereIn not sorted automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, where-in

my array from `$temp` is `Array ( [0] => 22 [1] => 26 [2] => 20 [3] => 24 )` or `22|26|20|24`

when I use `whereIn` like this

```
$robjeks = DB::table('objek')->whereIn('id', $temp)->get();
```

the result is `20|22|24|26|`

it's automatically sorted. I want it's not sorted.

how to make it same like `22|26|20|24`?

thanks for your attention.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel MySQL how to order results in the same order as in whereIn clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176245/laravel-mysql-how-to-order-results-in-the-same-order-as-in-wherein-clause)

Comment: which are the other fields in 'objek' table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel loses order when querying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248553/laravel-loses-order-when-querying/40250833)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Laravel. Read here first: [avoid Sorting by the MYSQL IN Keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195642/avoid-sorting-by-the-mysql-in-keyword)

Then, to do this, you can use this code:

```
$temp = [22, 26, 20, 24];
$tempStr = implode(',', $temp);
$robjeks = DB::table('objek')
    ->whereIn('id', $temp)
    ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $tempStr)"))
    ->get();
```

**You might be in risk with sql injection in this case**, so please sanitize the array of numbers accordingly.

Ref: [Laravel: order by where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704575/laravel-order-by-where-in)

Answer (score 1):

I think it has more to do with SQL rather than Laravel. If you are using autoincrement `id`, then obviously 22 is found before 26. If you want to change that you may follow this link: 
[Laravel: order by where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704575/laravel-order-by-where-in)

Or manually order your query yourself. eg.: `->orderBy('name')` or something else.