# How to get results based on elements in array with laravel whereIn?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, where-in

I have an array like this

```
$products = [350, 410, 362, 256, 193]
```

I have used this array to get results like this:

```
$searchResults = ProductSearch::whereIn('product_id', $products)->get();
```

In this result, I am not getting product with id 350 on first element in the result collection. Is there any way to achieve such result using ORM ?

Comment: You are already using ORM. Is this example not working for you?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 yes I want result in an order similar to the above array !

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify `ORDER BY` in an sql query, the order is undefined.

#### To define an order from your array, use `orderByRaw()`

```php
$products = [350, 410, 362, 256, 193]
 
$products_ordered = implode(',', $products);
 
$items = ProductSearch::whereIn('product_id', $products)
 ->orderByRaw("FIELD(product_id, $products_ordered)")
 ->get();
```

The order issue is not a Laravel issue, but an SQL issue. [Read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195642/avoid-sorting-by-the-mysql-in-keyword), where someone is having the same issue without Laravel. And these almost identical questions:

- [Laravel: order by where in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704575/laravel-order-by-where-in)
- [How to make Laravel whereIn not sorted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688648/how-to-make-laravel-wherein-not-sorted-automatically)
- [Laravel MySQL how to order results in the same order as in whereIn clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176245/laravel-mysql-how-to-order-results-in-the-same-order-as-in-wherein-clause)
- [Laravel loses order when querying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248553/laravel-loses-order-when-querying)

Comment: I have used this approach using ORM, but results are not as expected !

Comment: Please update your question with the current returned output and the expected output.

Comment: There is specific order right now, I want recrod with product_id = 350 at first and then 410 & so on !

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your table has a column(    product_id ) available?

Comment: Yes, that column exists !

Comment: and also 350 ID available or not?

Comment: ID is available, and records are not in order of above array !

Comment: You can check it by using 
    $searchresult = DB::table('productSearch')->whereIn('product_id', $products)->get();

Comment: Have tried that one, still not working !